# How to get time difference in seconds from one column via db2

Tags: db2

I have a table that contains a time column and I need to calculate its time duration by calculating the difference in seconds between current row time values and next row time values, and the last row would have 0 as timeduration in db2. I tried using timestampdiff to calculate but it doesn’t seem to work, how could I achieve this?

Current Table：

```
date        | title  | time      | timeduration(seconds)
02/06/2022  |  T1    |  01:09:07 | null
02/06/2022  |  T2    |  01:09:07 | null
02/06/2022  |  T3    |  01:09:35 | null
02/06/2022  |  T4    |  01:09:47 | null
02/06/2022  |  T5    |  01:09:49 | null
02/06/2022  |  T6    |  01:09:49 | null
02/06/2022  |  T7    |  01:09:51 | null
```

timeduration = next row time value - current row time value

expected output:

```
date        | title  | time      | timeduration(seconds)
02/06/2022  |  T1    |  01:09:07 | 0
02/06/2022  |  T2    |  01:09:07 | 28
02/06/2022  |  T3    |  01:09:35 | 12
02/06/2022  |  T4    |  01:09:47 | 2 
02/06/2022  |  T5    |  01:09:49 | 0
02/06/2022  |  T6    |  01:09:49 | 2
02/06/2022  |  T7    |  01:09:51 | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH T (date, title, time) AS
(
VALUES
  ('02/06/2022', 'T1', '01:09:07')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T3', '01:09:35')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T4', '01:09:47')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T5', '01:09:49')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T6', '01:09:49')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T2', '01:09:07')
, ('02/06/2022', 'T7', '01:09:51')
)
SELECT 
  T.*
, COALESCE (TIMESTAMPDIFF (2, CHAR (LEAD (TIMESTAMP (DATE, TIME)) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP (DATE, TIME)) - TIMESTAMP (DATE, TIME))), 0)
    AS "timeduration(seconds)"
FROM T
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP (DATE, TIME)
```

| DATE | TITLE | TIME | timeduration(seconds) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/06/2022 | T1 | 01:09:07 | 0 |
| 02/06/2022 | T2 | 01:09:07 | 28 |
| 02/06/2022 | T3 | 01:09:35 | 12 |
| 02/06/2022 | T4 | 01:09:47 | 2 |
| 02/06/2022 | T5 | 01:09:49 | 0 |
| 02/06/2022 | T6 | 01:09:49 | 2 |
| 02/06/2022 | T7 | 01:09:51 | 0 |